# how to understand list of soundcards; meaning of MID, HDMI, PCH

Tags: audio

Command `aplay -l` produces a list of "all soundcards and digital audio devices".

On my brand-new Fujitsu Esprimo desktop, I get:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC671 Analog [ALC671 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`lspci -v` command shows two audio devices:

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions Device 11e7
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at f7c34000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions Device 11eb
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at f7c30000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Now my questions:

How it comes my office computer has two sound cards? These are both standard on-board cards, right?

What's the meaning of MID, PCH, HDMI?

Which one is connected to the moss-green standard plug?

Comment: It's a Fujitsu Esprimo Desktop.

Comment: I edited the question to provide the output of `lspci -v`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What's the meaning of MID, PCH, HDMI?

**MID** is a compound acronym with an unenlightening expansion: it is the Message Signalled Interrupt Capability ID register in the C220 series chipset your machine uses.

(How did they manage to boil that unwieldy term down to MID, you ask? [MSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Signaled_Interrupts) is a well-established acronym in its own right, so this is the "MSI ID" register, or MID. They could just as well have called it the MSIID, or MSICID, but I guess people like [TLAs](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/T/TLA.html) too much. See section 17.1.1.25 in the [Intel 8/C220 series PCH datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/8-series-chipset-pch-datasheet.pdf).)

Anyway, MID isn't important here. What matters is that it's tied to the HDMI outputs, which is the true audio output device, from the user's perspective.

**[HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdmi)** is a digital audio/video transport, most often seen on consumer entertainment equipment like [Blu-ray players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluray), but also on some PCs, especially the sort designed to be used as [home theater PCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htpc). Since HDMI can carry sound as well as video, it shows up in your list of sound output devices. Some people do use it as a dedicated sound output, sending HDMI to a [DAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) while video goes out another path, such as VGA.

I don't know why you see three HDMI output paths, but it is almost certainly not because your computer has 3 HDMI output connectors, or even the capability of such. I hesitate to even guess what the distinction among them is, though if you post your `lspci -v` output, I could research the ICs involved and would probably figure it out.

**[PCH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub)** is what you'd call your actual "sound card," though it isn't actually a card in the machine. PCH is Intel's name for a family of ICs that include sound output. Because there have been many generations of PCH, you often see it followed by a fragment of the IC part number, like [PCH C220](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/8-series-chipset-pch-thermal-design-guide.html), which helps you decide whether a given driver is compatible with the particular PCH family variant on your motherboard.

> Which one is connected to the moss-green standard plug?

PCH.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what MID and PCH stand for, so I can't answer that part. [HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) is High-Definition Multimedia Interface. HDMI can carry audio, and it'd appear your machine has (or could have) 3 HDMI ports.

The moss-green plug is the analog audio, the last one listed.

Answer (score 1):

According to a topic on the gentoo.org forums, "The MID card doesn't work at all (alsamixer says: "This sound device does not have any controls."). So it's useless, yet it is made the default card for some reason. "

The fix for it, [as referenced on this post in the topic](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7447204.html?sid=74a28cf3d1b1f91f9924c1781ad9c816#7447204), is to add the following to the kernel commandline in your bootloader config: **snd_hda_intel.index=1**

This will set the default device to the PCH one instead of the MID one, which is your *green plug*. This may help you if you run into issues with the "default" sound device not working as expected.